# Javascript onsubmit with cgi action?

Tags: javascript, html, cgi, onsubmit

I have a html form and have a cgi script running on the action and then I have a javascript onsubmit function that should check if the radio button was filled out otherwise it wont submit.

```
<script>
function checkscript()
{
 .... check if a radio button was clicked otherwise dont submit.  
}
</script>

<form action="default.cgi" method="post" onsubmit="return checkscript()" enctype=
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<h1>Choose</h1>

<p><input type="radio" name="Radio" value="1" /><font size="5"
color="#0033CC">Instant Psychology</font><br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="Radio" value="2" /><font size="5"
color="#CC0000">Instant Geography</font><br />
<br />
<form/>
```

Can I do this in a Javascript function in the html file or do I need to do that in the cgi script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script works in all browsers. First, gets the inputs on the page, then loops through each checking the name attribute for Radio. As soon as it finds one Radio input that is checked (selected), it returns true which will submit the form. If, however, none of the inputs are checked (selected), the script returns false and prevents a submission.

```
function checkscript()
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0, l=inputs.length; i<l; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].name === "Radio" && inputs[i].checked) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can use jquery, you do this

```
function checkscript(){
  if($('#radio-button').is(':checked')) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

and yes, you can just place it in your html file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That won't work if you're using IDs correctly (every HTML element should have a unique ID). However, if your selector is $("[name=Radio]"), then it would work. You could also make the function body simply: return $("input[name=Radio]").is(":checked");

Comment: that is assuming you only have one radio button in your html page. But to solve that, you can always use class instead. Thanks for the heads up. =)